# show and click javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

How to make this code is available to click and show? I have tried by changing .hide() to .show() but still it's unable to click when the tabs is show.

```
<li id="tabs10">
    <a href="javascript: ;" >
        <span>SIMULASI</span>
    </a>
</li>
<script>$("#tabs10").hide();</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toggle** to show/hide as below:

```js
function showHideTab(){

$("#tabs10").toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="showHideTab()" value="Submit">
<li id="tabs10">
    <a href="javascript: ;" >
        <span>SIMULASI</span>
    </a>
</li>
```